# Free fax web app with an emphasis on privacy and security

Tags: web-apps, fax

Can anyone recommend a free web app that allows the user to send a private fax?

Here are the requirements:

1. Free of charge (gratis)
2. Does *not* require a credit card
3. Can fax up to 3 pages per day, preferably up to 5 pages.  A limit of 20 pages per month is fine.
4. Does ***not*** retain the fax once it has been sent.
5. Does not retain additional personal information.  For example, some services ask for the sender's name and telephone number for the cover page.  If provided, that information should not be retained.  Some services send a confirmation email that the fax has been sent.  It's preferred if they don't retain the email address, but not a deal-breaker if they do.
6. Uses reasonable security technologies to prevent anyone outside of the recipient (meaning anyone at their fax number) from reading the fax.
7. Although I would prefer a service that does not include any advertisements, I am okay if an advertisement is included on the cover page, but not on the faxed document itself.  If possible, please disclose in your answer if there are any ads, and where they are included.

Comment: Since sending a fax actually costs money _in call charges_ your first requirement is unlikely to be met. Also many jurisdictions have a requirement for the carrier to be assured of the originators identity and in some cases the actual content for some time in case the message sent was threatening, extorting, pornographic, etc. so you may have problems there. Also, any free service is likely to be geographically restricted - a UK provider may not let me send a fax to Australia for obvious reasons.

Comment: @SteveBarnes as for price, I think a "free service" might place "additional elements" on such a fax to cover its fees – if such a free service exists. And I'd rather not bet the results would always be welcome :)

Comment: @Izzy I suspect that the people who are being faxed might not welcome some free providers having their number

Comment: Thanks gentlemen.  I've included information regarding advertising in the question.

Comment: Why not place the contents of the file into a password encrypted attachment?  Then call them the password is .............. <hang up>  Even if someone else gets it, it is encrypted.